# What does "Verlorensein" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am trying to understand the following phrase:

> Du gibst das Leben mit einem klaren Sinn, beendest das Verlorensein,
> schenkst einen Neubeginn.

But I couldn't see the meaning of "Verlorensein". I found that there is a verb "verlieren", which means to lose, and I suspect that sein is a sufix here that converts this verb into a noun, but I don't know.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lit. the state of being lost.

Sein is not a suffix but rather a verb in its own right - and like any verb can be used as a noun (Gerundium - like a gerund in English) when added an article before its infinitive form.

And in this case you just add an adverb (verloren - lost, the perfect form of verlieren, which can serve as an adverb) before to describe the function of the verb (sein - to be) so to say,

For example, the word "Bewusstsein" (conciousness) is literally "being concious", but as a gerund similar to "Wiedersehen", "Bereitstellen" etc.

Comment: That was lighting, thank you. I also wonder: How to determine the article that must be added before the verb to construct the noun?

Comment: @LazarusFrost Nouns ending with "sein" are always neuter. They are compound words with "das Sein".

Comment: All "Gerundium"s are neuter, be it "das Sein" or "das Verlieren". Whether definite or indefinite, I'm not sure of an exact rule, it depends on context.

Comment: That is a tricky one, as the english expression being lost means "sich verirrt haben", which is not the same as "verloren sein".

Comment: "sich verirrt haben" is in a more locative sense, whilst "verloren sein" would be more more in a more abstract or emotional sense, I think "being lost" can mean both.

Answer (score 1):

"Verlorensein" means the state of being lost. The equivalent sentence (to the noun) is "Du bist verloren." You can follow this recipe for a number of adjectives, which are often related to feelings:

- Glücklichsein
- Traurigsein
- Einsamsein
- ...

Comment: That is a tricky one, as the english expression _being lost_ means "sich verirrt haben", which is not the same as "verloren sein".

Answer (score 0):

German does not allow spaces in compounds. If you make up compound nouns that have a verb component, that verb must be a built-in. Translate them as gerunds with an extra constituent:

- das Kleinsein — being small
- das Rechthaben — having a point
- das Weiterbestehenkönnen — being able to continue to exist
- das Verlorensein — being lost

> Du […] beendest das Verlorensein. — You stop (me) being lost.

So the translation is often straightforward. But be careful about perfect expressions as those may require *sein* in German, but have to be replicated as perfect in English.

- das Gegangensein — having gone
- das Gewesensein — having been

And be extra careful with expressions that look like perfect but aren't.

- das Gefangensein — being trapped

The perfect is

- das Gefangenhaben — having caught